# Socket not closed with Cgminer and P2pool

Tags: sockets, cgminer

I have some issues with cgminer client (https://github.com/dmaxl/cgminer) and the last p2pool release.
The cgminer open sockets with p2pool until cgminer crashes after 3 to 4 hours.
I have to restart my cgminer automatically to clean the sockets opened.

At the same time my Litecoind on the P2pool server return a lot of "VerifySignature failed: Non-canonical signature: S value is unnecessarily high" errors when cgminer is mining. Deleting the database didn't fix the error.

```
2016-01-09 10:23:06 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool: : ConnectInputs failed cfe056c00ba6a7755fcdb1f3f2d1ea34ba591e2629adac0d2848240415f5e35a 2016-01-09 10:23:06 ERROR: CScriptCheck():
```

Very strange ... My platform worked correctly until I update all the softwares (p2pool / cgminer and litecoind).

Any idea how to correct this issue ? Is-it a bad management of the Litecoind errors from cgminer ?